# haskell sorting

Tags: sorting, haskell, tuples

How can it be done in most simply way to write (or maybe there is something embedded in haskell) function which takse as arguments list of tuples (String, Int)  and Int x and return top x tuples as list according to x value.

I wonder if its possible to write a function which also takes 3 argument which is the name of (or index) of filed in tuple according to which sorting has to be done.

What are best solutions to make it quite generic?

Comment: I know your question is probably more for your own curiosity, but what are you doing with the data? Is a sorted list really what you want to end up with? We're not shuffling around elements in low-level arrays in C country anymore and haskell gives you easy access to a whole zoo of interesting data types which probably are more appropriate for doing whatever you're going to be doing with the "sorted" data.

Comment: The reason is that Im learning and want to know what are possibilities, and sort function is the one that everyone understand so the explenation is easier. Ofcourse I know about embedded types, still learning, thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
take x $ sortBy (compare `on` fst) [("asd", 1), ...]
```

`take x` takes the first x items from the sorted list. `sortBy` sorts the list given as second argument using the sorting function given as the first argument. `` (compare `on` fst) `` compares the first values of each tuple.
Note that this example compares the first value of each tuple for sorting. To sort by the second value, replace `fst` with `snd`.

You see that the `sortBy` function is very generic, as it lets you define the function used to compare the values. The function takes two arguments and should return one of LT, EQ or GT. Note that the function `compare` requires both arguments to derive from `Ord`. The helper function `on` can be found in the module `Data.Function`. The function `sortBy` is in the module `Data.List`.

EDIT:
Here is a complete working example that sorts a list of tuples by comparing their first values and prints the first 2 tuples of the resulting list. Note that I replaced the `on` from the example above with a equivalent function that shows what `on` does internally.

```
import Data.Function
import Data.List

main = print $ mySort [("foo", 1), ("bar", 2), ("baz", 3), ("quux", 4)] 2

mySort list x = take x $ sortBy (\ x y -> compare (fst x) (fst y)) list
```

EDIT:
As Tom Lokhorst pointed out in his comment, the function `comparing` from the module `Data.Ord` is a more readable replacement/shortcut for `on compare`, so the above could also be written as `sortBy (comparing fst)`.

Comment: Note that the `comparing` function from `Data.Ord` is the same as `on compare`. So you could also write `sortBy (comparing fst) list`.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that one.

Comment: Should you not `take` before you `sortBy`? mySort can potentially take an infinite list.

Comment: Since `base-4.8.0.0`, `Data.List` provides `sortOn` (in this case: `sortOn fst`). @AndreArtus if you take first, you are just getting the first x, not the top x according to sorting. Sorting an infinite list doesn't really make sense anyway!