# How do I use std::set with a comparator that applies a projection to the key?

Tags: c++, stdset

Suppose I have a set (or map) of strings, and I want to use a custom comparator that compares only the first 5 characters. So "abcde" and "abcdef" are the same in my set.

```
using MySet = std::set<std::string, Cmp>;
```

What is the best way to write Cmp?

The obvious way is like this:

```
struct Cmp
{
    bool operator()(const string& x, const string& y) const
    {
        return x.substr(0, 5) < y.substr(0, 5);
    }
};
```

The problem is that this code repeats `.substr(0, 5)`. In this example it's pretty short, but in the general case it could be longer. I want to avoid this repeating code.

In general, given the types `T1, T2` and the function `T2 key(T1& const)`, I want a set of `T1` elements that compares according to `key(a) < key(b)`, where comparison on `T2` is already well-defined. What is the best way to write this? I thought about writing a new `class KeyBaseSet`, but that would be over-designing for my single use-case. Is there some way to do this using `std` or Boost?

I'm looking for something similar to the `key` argument when sorting in Python (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions), or the `` compare `on` ``  idiom in Haskell (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2788262/351105).

Comment: Inexperienced in c++ as I am, pass a pointer to the beginning of each string and use strncmp(x, y, 5)

Comment: The biggest problem with your code is that calling `substr` allocates a new string, and doing that twice just to compare them makes comparison a lot more expensive than it should be.  @Evg's answer fixes this in a nice way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize `Cmp` with a key policy. Minimal example:

```
template<class Key>
struct Compare_on {
    Compare_on(Key key = Key()) : key_(key)
    {}

    template<class T>
    bool operator()(const T& x, const T& y) const {
        return key_(x) < key_(y);
    }

private:
    Key key_;
};

struct First3 {
    std::string_view operator()(const std::string& s) const {
        return std::string_view(s).substr(0, 3);
    }
};

// Example:
std::set<std::string, Compare_on<First3>> set;
set.insert("abc1");
set.insert("abc2");
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/UHmKTH)

---

`Compare_on` can be improved by making it a [transparent comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators):

```
template<class Key>
struct Compare_on {
    using is_transparent = void;

    Compare_on(Key key = Key()) : key_(key)
    {}

    template<class T1, class T2>
    bool operator()(const T1& x, const T2& y) const {
        return key_(x) < key_(y);
    }

private:
    Key key_;
};

struct First3 {
    template<class T>
    std::string_view operator()(const T& s) const {
        return std::string_view(s).substr(0, 3);
    }
};
```

Now when we do

```
auto pos = set.find("abc");
```

no temporary `std::string` will be constructed for the string literal `"abc"`.

[Demo 2](https://godbolt.org/z/hHbZp3)

Comment: This is a nice solution, and now that you wrote it, I see that it's pretty short as well! BTW, the optimization of not copying the string is nice, but in my question it was just an example - I don't really need this exact key comparison.

Comment: @TomerVromen, depending on your use case, you might still benefit from transparent comparisons if `find` argument type is different from set key type.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be solved with higher order functions. Essentially a function that takes the `T2 key(const T1&)` function and returns a new function that can be used as comparator for the `std::set`. Something like:

```
auto make_comp(T key) {
    return [key](const auto& v1, const auto& v2){return key(v1) < key(v2);};
}
```

Obviously this example requires generic lambdas, but it should be possible to achieve this with template structs as well :)

It should be possible to define a set as `std::set<decltype(make_comp([](){...}))>`.

Comment: Copying the values is often pretty wasteful.

Comment: yes. I was on the phone and writing proper c++ here is a pain. however, I think the compiler will get it in most of the cases and elude the copy.